# Received ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity while passing image to keras ocr

Tags: python, numpy, keras, ocr, tf.keras

i expected the function to accept the image and read the text from it

here's my function

```
    def read_image(self, image):
            keras_pipeline = keras_ocr.pipeline.Pipeline()
            img = glob(image)
            results = keras_pipeline.recognize(img)

            final_sentence = " ".join(pd.DataFrame(results[0], columns=['text', 'bbox']).text)
            return final_sentence
```

instead I got an error in return stating :

```
File "C:\Users\arpit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 552, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\arpit\Desktop\demo\my_approach\app.py", line 26, in <module>
    ocr_text = tutor.read_image(uploaded_file.name)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\arpit\Desktop\demo\my_approach\brain.py", line 15, in read_image
    results = k_pipeline.recognize(img)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\arpit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras_ocr\pipeline.py", line 50, in recognize
    ).max(axis=0)
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\arpit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 41, in _amax
    return umr_maximum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims, initial, where)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I wonder if the glob list is empty?